# How to round to the nearest human readable number in log-scale?

Tags: r

For numbers between 1 and 10, I want to round into any of the four numbers, 1, 2, 5, and 10.

For numbers between 10 and 100, I want to round into any of the four numbers, 10, 20, 50, and 100.

For numbers between .1 and 1, I want to round into any of the four numbers, .1, .2, .5 and 1.

For other ranges, the rounding rule is similar except scaled by a power of 10.

I may use a for-loop and if-else to program this. But it will not be efficient. Can anybody provide a more efficient solution (e.g., based on vectorized operations)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses a similar idea as the one above, with a twist; here, I am mapping the vector of desired values to the order of magnitude of `x` and then finding the closest match.

```r
custom.round <- function(x, r = c(1,2,5,10)){

  m <- 10^(floor(log10(x)))
  r[[which.min(abs((m * r) - x))]] * m

## use this other variation if the desired behavior is "rounding" in log-scale
# r[[which.min(abs(r - (x/m)))]] * m
    
}


sapply(c(.009,0.012,.501,.499,1.2,4.5,19,21), custom.round)
#> [1]  0.01  0.01  0.50  0.50  1.00  5.00 20.00 20.00
```

Comment: Your rounding is in the original scale, roundNicely is in the log10-scale.. ```R> custom.round(1.5)
[1] 1```, ```R> roundNicely(1.5)
[1] 2```. That seems to be the difference.

Comment: @user1424739 ```r[[which.min(abs(r - (x/m)))]] * m``` use this one instead if you want the log-scale comparison/rounding.

Answer (score 2):

First I define a function to return the value of `v` closest to the scalar `x`.

Then in the second function I first take the floor of `log10(x)` to get the correct order of magnitude, then find which of `log10(c(1,2,5,10))` the remainder is closest to, and reassemble.

```
closestTo <- function(x, v){
  sapply(x , function(x) v[which.min(abs(v-x))])
}
roundNicely <- function(x){
  10^(floor(log(x,10)) + closestTo(log(x,10)%%1, log10(c(1,2,5,10))))
}


> roundNicely(c(.009,0.012,.501,.499,1.2,4.5,19,21))
[1]  0.01  0.01  0.50  0.50  1.00  5.00 20.00 20.00
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a slightly more efficient version of *@George Savva*'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71773103/6574038). It uses `vapply` and avoids redundant calculations.

```
f <- \(x) {
  ls <- log10(c(1, 2, 5, 10))
  lx <- log10(x)
  t2 <- vapply(lx %% 1, \(r) ls[which.min(abs(ls - r))], numeric(1L))
  10^(floor(lx) + t2)
}

x <- runif(5e5)
stopifnot(all.equal(f(x), roundNicely(x)))
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(f=f(x), rNice=roundNicely(x), times=3L)
# Unit: milliseconds
#  expr      min       lq      mean    median       uq       max neval cld
#     f 774.6042 775.2385  810.7454  775.8729  828.816  881.7592     3  a 
# rNice 940.4319 997.3334 1045.3822 1054.2350 1097.857 1141.4798     3   b
```

Comment: Nice.  I never think to use `vapply`.

Comment: What is `\(x)`?

Comment: @user1424739 It's the new abbreviation for `function(x)` implemented since R >= 4.1. You probably should update your R.

Comment: Why use `numeric(1)` instead of just `0`?

Comment: @user1424739 Well, if result length is 2, your version would be `rep(0, 2)`?

Comment: I don't understand your question. `R> str(numeric(1))
 num 0
 R> str(numeric(0))
 num(0)`. `numeric(1)` and `0` are exactly the same. Do you see when they will make a difference in the context of the question?

Comment: @user1424739 `0` is a vector of type `"double"` of length one and a very special case of `vapply`, try `vapply(1000, \(x) rep.int(x, x), numeric(1000L))`. `numeric(1)` is more general and has better didactic value.